# Is it possible to change the subimage which my css sprite displays with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want my image sprites to display another subimage which i have in my image file based on which page the user is on.  I can identify the page in javascript and have my css sprites displayed correctly, currently inside li tags in an unordered list which include anchor tags as well.

Here is an example of my css

```
<style type="text/css">
#theList{position:relative;}
#theList li{margin:0;padding:0;list-style:none;position:absolute;}
#theList li, #navlist a{height:40px;display:block;}


#one{left:-10px;top:-55px;width:200px;}
#one{background:url('../../images/dashboardNavigationMasterSprite.jpg') 0px 0px;}
#one a:hover{background: url('../../images/dashboardNavigationMasterSprite.jpg') 0px -40px;}

#two{left:193px;top:-55px;width:200px;}
#two{background:url('../../images/dashboardNavigationMasterSprite.jpg') -202px 0px;}
#two a:hover{background: url('../../images/dashboardNavigationMasterSprite.jpg') -202px -40px;}
</style>
```

And here is my html

```
<ul id="theList">
<li id="one"><a href="http://bert2007sql64/sites/budgettool/FIDs/Pages/Dashboards/Dashboard_Exec_Home.aspx"></a></li>
  <li id="two"><a href="http://bert2007sql64/sites/budgettool/FIDs/Pages/Dashboards/Dashboard_Budget_Controls.aspx"></a></li>
```

Basically what I am wondering is how can I access and change the xpos and ypos attributes
using javascript or jquery possibly.  The xpos and ypos values i am trying to manipulate are the ones listed in the line below

```
#one{background:url('../../images/dashboardNavigationMasterSprite.jpg') 0px 0px;}
```

Thankyaverymuch,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change it programatically like this (using JQuery)

```
$('#id').css( {backgroundPosition: "0 0"} )
```

[Here](http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/jquery-bg-image-animations/) you got an excellent example

something (not tested) that you could try:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#one').css( {backgroundPosition: "20px 10px"} )
    });
</script>
```

Comment: This answer alludes to there being only one image URL property, and the position is shifted for each li instance. There should be no need for repeating the background-image URL. Your CSS could then consist of a list of id's in normal state, and the same list in hover state.

Comment: MTF I believe I understand what your saying, so have three html unordered lists and then handle visibilty from there?

Answer (score 1):

Expand your styling so that differnet classes (or some other CSS-selector-criteria) on the same tags point to different positions within your sprite. Then in Javascript, change the classes of the tags to get the differnet images.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you using jQuery:

```
$('#one').css( 'backgroundPosition', '0px 0px' );
```